# 2 сетевухи на компе - проверить провод

Tags: ip, tcp-ip, ethernet, alias

Есть машинка с двумя сетевыми картами
С возможностями alias могу настроить аж 4 ip

Но не могу настроить 2 адреса в одной подсети

Я могу проверить работоспособность “шнурка” из одной сетевой карты в другую? Как?

Comment: Операционная система есть?

Comment: "Но не могу настроить 2 адреса в одной подсети" - почему не можете?

Comment: Qnx (кпда нетрино)

Comment: en0: flags=80008843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,SHIM> mtu 1500
address: 00:e0:4c:b0:0e:53
media: Ethernet 100baseTX full-duplex
status: active
inet 169.254.153.199 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 169.254.153.255
inet alias 192.168.3.131 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.3.255
en1: flags=80008843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,SHIM> mtu 1500
address: 00:80:48:34:c9:28
media: Ethernet 100baseTX full-duplex
status: active
inet 169.254.154.199 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 169.254.154.255
А сделать обе 153 или 154 невозможно. Те проверить провод между ними тоже

Answer (score 1):

Используйте утилиту arping -I eth0 ip_адрес при этом на картах можно задавать разные подсети, утилита будет работать.
Либо можно интерфейсы разносить в разные namespaces, но это намного сложнее.